# trying to install wp but i have no clue on hosting and servers

Tags: database, hosting

I'm trying to install Word Press and I can't figure out the database connection fields for the wp-config file.How do I figure out what server and host I have?  Is there a program or app that can do all this for me?

I've searched both browser and windows files with the keywords "localhost and my server" and it didn't help.Will install Bluehost and Installatron be of any help?

Comment: Are you trying to install WP locally or on Bluehost, if Bluehost you have to create a database, user and grant all permissions to the user for that DB using cPanel.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to install. I can't figure out how to get my database connection info.  Can you assist me on how to do it.  I've been stuck at this part for about a week.

Comment: down voted as at this point there is not way to answer this question. please edit the question and include **all** relevant details.

Comment: Simply put — what you have to do and how depends _on your hosting_. If you went with some unmanaged hosting without support, you might want to reconsider and switch to something more managed and friendly to novice users.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks info, but I think you only need a guidance on how to start.

**If you want do develop locally**, you should install XAMPP, WAMPP or any other program that 'emulates' a server in your computer.

After you do that, you need to configure your database with PhpMyAdmin for example, to create the database, the user, and set a password.

With that done, you place the WordPress files in the specific folder and run something like 'localhost/projectname' in your browser.

There are a lot of tutorials on the web on how to do that, if you have no idea how to.

**If you want to develop on a webserver**, you will have to do the same thing, but if you have a CPanel, creating the database and the user will be easier for you, since you can use 'database wizard' on most CPanels.

Again, there is a lot of tutorials online on how to do that and even some CPanels have that tutorials.